# Telegram как отправить файл Post запросом

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Подскажите как **без библиотек** разных отправить файл **.txt**, **.rar** в телеграмм Https Post запросом?! 
Ничего годного не нашёл, очень мало информации, или же я плохо ищу.

Есть [Справочник по Bot API](https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots/api#making-requests)

Я так понял для загрузки файлов нужно использовать `multipart/form-data` с этим я особо не работал, поэтому буду благодарен если кто-то конкретно опишет каждую операцию по отправки файла.

Answer (score 0):

```
## Not run: 
bot <- Bot(token = bot_token("RTelegramBot"))
chat_id <- user_id("Me")
photo_url <- "https://telegram.org/img/t_logo.png"

bot$sendPhoto(
  chat_id = chat_id,
  photo = photo_url,
  caption = "Telegram Logo"
)

## End(Not run)
```

Comment: при чем тут фото и файл .txt, .rar?